# How can I keep the corresponding drive letters of different hard disks in the same slot of the server unchanged?

Tags: disk

For example, slot 5 of the server has hard disk A. The drive letter of hard disk A is /dev/sda. If hard disk A is damaged, replace hard disk B with the /dev/sda drive letter

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What operating system are you using? As far as I know, only Windows uses letters ("A", "B" etc) as you describe. Do you just mean the name of the drive, sd**a**, sd**b** etc? If you replace a drive, it should get the same name, but the details can depend on the operating system.

Comment: Following up on the comment by @terdon, you probably do not need to refer to `/dev/sda?` anywhere. If you are mounting disks, you can use the UUID of the filesystem to mount the available partitions. Also, if the first disk is "damaged", will it even be recognized by the OS and thus not assigned a /dev/sd? device?